# xcodebuild how to run several testExamples functions without restarting the app under testing

Tags: xcode, xctest

This command will run UI test on Simulator for 2 test cases :

> xcodebuild test -project MyLib.xcodeproj -scheme MyAppUITests -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=11.3,name=iPhone 5s' -only-testing:MyAppUITests/MyAppUITests/testExample -only-testing:MyAppUITests/MyAppUITests/testExample2|xcpretty --test --color

This cause **testExample** and **testExample2** to be executed but the app under test is restarted between the 2 test cases executions, despite the fact that test setup is the same for both.

How could I keep the app started just once ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do multiple actions in a row without a restart in between, they need to be done as part of a single test method.

The reason that the app is restarted between each test is to ensure that the outcome of each test is independent from the others. Repeating the setup for each test is essential if you want to ensure that when a test fails, it has failed because there is something wrong with *that test case*.

If you chain many tests together without resetting the state, and one part of the test fails, the other parts of the test will be affected and you will not have clear test results.

While it is true that the `setUp()` method runs multiple times as part of this framework, this is necessary to ensure test independence. The power of automated UI tests lies in the automation (no manual effort required for repeated execution of the same tests) and the data they can give you (a clear breakdown of which features are or are not working), not in their speed. Restarting the app between each test and running the `setUp()` for each test should not increase the time complexity of the execution of your test suite.

---

For example, say you have four components, A, B, C and D, and B breaks. A, C and D are all still working.

If you only have one large test method, `testAAndBAndCAndD()`, and it fails, you will be unable to tell whether A, B, C or D are broken, or if all of them are broken.

Whereas if you have four separate tests, `testA()`, `testB()`, `testC()` and `testD()`, only `testB()` will fail and you will instantly know from the test results that the problem lies with B.

I hope this illustrates why it is necessary to restart the app between each test.

Comment: I understand very well the decoupling test theory and the why, so you are fully right. But I have a specific situation that could be long to explain here, out of scope. I'm just looking for an option to not restart my App between test cases. But I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: The problem is my tear down is empty but Xcuitest close the app after test anyways. Did you have any idea to avoid that behavior ?

Comment: You cannot avoid that behaviour, it is built into XCTest

Comment: OK Oletha, I see. I try to avoid this constraint by running several tests on a row. But the xcodebuild could not run the same test twice. In this example below testExample1 is executed juste once.  

xcodebuild test -project MyLib.xcodeproj -scheme MyAppUITests -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,OS=11.3,name=iPhone 5s' -only-testing:MyAppUITests/MyAppUITests/testExample1 -only-testing:MyAppUITests/MyAppUITests/testExample2 -only-testing:MyAppUITests/MyAppUITests/testExample1|xcpretty --test --color


  Executed 2 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 7.335 (7.340) seconds